# How can we use case insensitive propertyName in criteria in nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, criteria

In simple SQL we can write queries where the field names are case insensitive. For example, we want to query on `Student` table and it has one field called `Name`. We can write a query like this (in MS SQL):

```
select * from Student where name = "John"
```

See here we have used `name` instead of `Name`, but it still runs properly.

But when I write a criteria in nHibernate like this

```
session.createCriteria("Student")
.Add(Restrictions.Eq("name","John")).List()
```

It fails with the error `could not resolve property: name of Student`.

Is there any way we can make the field/property names case insensitive in criteria as direct SQL queries.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. Property names are case sensitive.

Long answer: you can parse your user's input and use reflection to find the correct property names.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a criteria query you are querying POCOs and their properties - and of course names in C# are case sensitive.  As far as I know, HQL queryies are case sensitive too, so you probably are out of luck.

Comment: In our system, the end user can write queries in a particular format. To make the life of the users easy, we are thinking of making the field names case insensitive. That's all.

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to directly run queries that a user enters anyway, from a security point of view.

Comment: They cannot run any queries. As I said they don't enter direct queries, there is strict format.